# What is the standard way in gmaps4rails for dynamically resetting marker icons / pictures?

Tags: gmaps4rails

All I want to do is dynamically reset a marker's icon.  For example, suppose a red marker is pinned to a specific location on the map.  A user-interaction occurs which requires the red marker to become yellow.  In this case, I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
      var icon = marker.serviceObject.getIcon();
      if ($("#chooseJobsForWorkSite ul li input:checked").size() > 0) {
        icon.url = "/assets/purple_MarkerT.png";
      } else {
        icon.url = "/assets/green_MarkerS.png";
      }
      marker.serviceObject.setIcon(icon);
```

This works fine for a single marker, but when I loop across this code for more than
one marker, something goes wrong -- I do not get the desired colors for all markers.

Comment: I really don't understand how the loop could affect the behavior here. You're sure of your code?

Comment: My code is rather complicated, but Chrome does not indicate any errors during the code-branch where the problem occurs.  I have resolved the problem by simply replacing markers.  I'll post a code sample shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the replaceMarkers API method.  Here's the code that worked:

```
var replacementMarkers = new Array();
for (var k = 0; k < activeMarkers.length; ++k) {
  var marker = activeMarkers[k];

  var iconUrl = null;
  if ($.inArray(marker, taskMarkers) >= 0) {
    iconUrl = "/assets/purple_MarkerT.png";
  } else {
    iconUrl = "/assets/green_MarkerS.png";
  }

  replacementMarkers.push({
    "lat": marker.lat.toString(),
    "lng": marker.lng.toString(),
    "picture": iconUrl,
    "id": marker.id,
    "description": marker.description
  });
}

// Delay the replacement operation because in some instances, we reach this branch via the Gmaps.map.callback.
// In that case, I prefer to defer touching the gmap4rails until the current branch is done.

window.setTimeout(function() {
  Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(replacementMarkers);
  resetAddressMarkers();
}, 25);
```